# Hypotenuse and angle ratio relationship

Tags: geometry

In triangle ABC $\angle BAC=90$, $\angle ABC$:$\angle ACB $=1:2 and AC = 4cm.  Calculate the length of BC. 
I tried this by constructing an equilateral triangle as in the figure. 
I am interested in the solution using Pythagoras theorem

Answer (score 0):

Well if $\angle BAC = 90^\circ$ and $\angle ABC : \angle ACB = 1:2$, this means $\angle ABC = 60^\circ$ and $\angle ACB = 30^\circ$. Now $AC = 4$ and $BC = \sqrt{AB^2 + AC^2}$. But $AB = BC\cos(60^\circ)$.

Comment: Can there be a solution without trigonometric relationships being used. Can it be done with basic geometrical concepts

Answer (score 0):

> $$\angle BAC=90^o,\angle ABC:\angle ACB=1:2,AC=4$$

Draw a line through A such that $\angle BAD=60^o$.Let it intersect BC at D. Now ADB is an equilateral triangle. So:
$$AD=DB=BA,\angle ADB=\angle DBA=\angle BAD=60^o$$
[image]

As $$\angle ADC=180^0-\angle ADB=120^o$$
In $\triangle ACD$
$$\angle DAC=180^o-\angle ACD-\angle CDA=180^o-30^o-120^o=30^o$$
So $\angle ACD=\angle CAD$, So sides $$AD=CD$$
Now let $BA=x$, So $$AB=BD=DA=x\\AD=CD=x$$
Apply pythagoreas theorem in $\triangle ABC$:
$$AB^2+AC^2=BC^2$$
So:
$$x^2+AC^2=(2x)^2=4x^2\\AC^2=3x^2\implies AC=\sqrt3x$$
As:
$$AC=\sqrt3x=4\implies x=4/\sqrt3$$
Hence $$\boxed {BC=2x=8/\sqrt3}$$